# How to cast a composite interface type to it implementation type

Tags: go, struct, interface, casting

I have a simple function that returns an interface `LockInterface` map which is fully implemented by a struct `InterfaceImpl`. Is there a way to cast the composite map `LockInterface` into `InterfaceImpl` ?

While I was writing this question a solution came to mind and that is to cast individual value of the `map[string]LockInterface` to a new map `map[string]LockImpl` but I am still curious if there is no easier way to do this.

My goal is to be able to `LockList()["foo"].B()`. Notice how B() is not in the interface signature

```
type LockInterface interface {
    A()
}

//fully implements lockInterface
type LockImp struct {
    x string
}
func (a LockImp) A() {}
func (l Lock) B() {
}

//factory
func NewLock() LockInterface {
    return &LockImp{}
}

func LockList()map[string]LockInterface{
    return make(map[string]LockInterface)
}

func main() {
    //Not okay
    // invalid operation: list (variable of type map[string]LockInterface) is not an interface
    list := LockList()
    a, b := list.(map[string]LockImp)

    //Okay
    // list := LockList()[""]
    // a, b := list.(LockImp)
}
```

Comment: You have to type assert individual elements of the map to `LockImp`. I am assuming the method `B` belongs to `LockImp` and not to `Lock` as shown in the code

Comment: Your code read like Java/C#. Covariance in Java/C# works differently than in Go. Try to write Go code (this is not an answer to your question -- Burak's is -- but a hopefully helpful advice).